# PHP MySQL Объединить две строки в одну и соединить с другой таблицей

Tags: php, mysql, sql, запрос, выборка

Интересует вариант как сделать запрос максимально (или приблизительно) продуктивным если можно)
Суть:

Есть две таблицы:

Table1

```
ID | Name
1  | Вася
2  | Петя
```

Table2

```
ID | ParentID | Value
1  |        1 |     1
2  |        1 |     2
3  |        2 |     3
4  |        2 |     4
```

Когда я делаю так:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Value FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ParentID
```

То получаю следующее

```
Name | Value
Вася |     1
Вася |     2
Петя |     3
Петя |     4
```

Но желательно чтобы было вот так

```
Name | Value1 | Value2
Вася |      1 |      2
Петя |      3 |      4
```

Или так

```
Name | Value
Вася |    1,2
Петя |    3,4
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT( )` для `Или так ` используйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Value) FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ParentID
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) - Объединяет строки с указанным разделителем. По умолчанию разделитель запятая.